# How to convert a .pbix file to Excel in PowerBI using python

Tags: python, excel, powerbi

I am using the PowerBI rest API as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/reports/exportreport) to get a report. I am receiving report in a *.pbix* file.

Can I convert this file to Excel file using Python?

I am using following Python code for receiving a file from API.

```
# data contains api response
target_path = '/path/test.pbix'
handle = open(target_path, "wb")
for chunk in data.iter_content(chunk_size=512):
    if chunk:
        handle.write(chunk)
handle.close()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Power BI Desktop, it's not supported to get data from an existing .PBIX file directly via Get Data option.

However, we can get another .PBIX file data in a new .PBIX file use below two methods:

a. Use Copy Table option to copy all table data. Then in a new .PBIx file, click Enter Data option, paste the table.

b. Export data from visual to a .CSV file. Then in a new .PBIX file, retrieve data from this .CSV file via Get Data->CSV. For more information, please refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/visuals/power-bi-visualization-export-data).

You can not import the PowerBI data into the Excel. You can export the data from powerbi visuals and can create a new data model in powerpivot Excel or adhoc analysis.

You can also upload your powerbi file to Service and use Analyze in Excel feature to browse the cube but data modifications are not allowed in that case.

Comment: Yes. A .pbix is basically a dataset and DAX transformations and visual configurations to present data from them. It also carries a snapshot of the data. It requires an active "engine" to turn that into a "report". If you don't need the effect of DAX and the visuals, you could extract the code for the dataset's data sources, drop them into an Excel workbook. If you do need the DAX, use Analyze in Excel as described above.